# Cannot send message to SQL Server 2008 Service Broker: The message type '<message type>' is not part of the service contract

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I'm trying to learn the basics of Service Broker, and have created an application originally based on the SSMS template.  However I can't send a message to my queue.  It just says the message type is not part of the service contract.

The absolute bare minimum I need to recreate this is the following batch:

```
USE [test_db]
GO

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [test_message] 
AUTHORIZATION [dbo] 
VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML
GO

CREATE CONTRACT [test_contract] 
AUTHORIZATION [dbo] (
    [test_message] SENT BY ANY
)
GO

CREATE QUEUE [dbo].[test_queue] 
WITH STATUS = ON 
    ,RETENTION = OFF
    --,ACTIVATION (
    --   STATUS = ON 
    --  ,PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[test_activator]
    --  ,MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1
    --  ,EXECUTE AS N'dbo'  
    --) 
ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

CREATE SERVICE [test_service]  
AUTHORIZATION [dbo] 
ON QUEUE [dbo].[test_queue] (
    [test_contract]
)
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @dialog_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    BEGIN DIALOG @dialog_handle
    FROM SERVICE test_service
    TO SERVICE N'test_service';

        SEND ON CONVERSATION @dialog_handle
        MESSAGE TYPE test_message (N'<test />');

    END CONVERSATION @dialog_handle;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

...which yields:

```
Msg 8431, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The message type 'test_message' is not part of the service contract.
```

I only need to be able to send asynchronous messages within the same database.  There are no remote connections to consider, and I don't strictly even need to handle a reply.

I've checked and double-checked that the message type, contract, queue and service all exist and the properties of the contract says that the message type *is* included

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your minimal example code, which help me to correct my code. After two days of debugging, I got it running :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN DIALOG @dialog_handle
FROM SERVICE test_service
TO SERVICE N'test_service'
ON CONTRACT test_contract;
```

Comment: Thanks @DenisValeev -- I love it when it's simple!!

Answer (score 4):

As Denis already answered, you're missing the `ON CONTRACT test_contract`.

If you omit it then the `DEFAULT` contract is used. Every database has a contract named `DEFAULT` which has one message type, also named `DEFAULT`. The `DEFAULT` contract is used when you omit any contract in `BEGIN DIALOG` and the `DEFAULT` message type is used when you omit the message type in `SEND`:

```
BEGIN DIALOG @dialog_handle
    FROM SERVICE test_service
    TO SERVICE N'test_service'; <-- will use the DEFAULT contract

SEND ON CONVERSATION @dialog_handle 
    (N'<test />'); <-- will use the DEFAULT message type
```

`DEFAULT` message type has no validation. The `DEFAULT` contract binds the `DEFAULT` message type to both initiator and target (both can send the message in this contract, ie. `SENT BY ANY`). Contract and message type names are always case sensitive, irrelevant of database collation, so the name `DEFAULT` is case sensitive.